# Rsync ACLs over NFSv4 to EXT4

Tags: acl, rsync, nfs

I'm trying to rsync with options -AX over an NFSv4 mount to an ext4 drive that has acl and user_xattr enabled. The comannd

```
rsync -aAX /data/ /mnt/back/data
```

results in

```
rsync: rsync_xal_set: lsetxattr(""/mnt/back/data/Users/user/Documents/Desktop"","security.NTACL") failed: Operation not supported (95)
```

along with all the other files.
Running the same command to a local folder works perfect so it must have something to do with NFS4 or EXT4 on the Server side.

My fstab mount

```
UUID=732683f0-e6ac-42d6-a492-e07643d7719c /media/back   ext4    defaults,acl,user_xattr,barrier=1       0       0
```

My nfs exports file

```
/media/back     10.111.106.3(fsid=0,rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

My mount command

```
mount -t nfs4 -o proto=tcp,port=2049 10.111.106.12:/ /mnt/back
```

Version info:

Server

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2
```

Client

```
Ubuntu 14.04.2
rsync 3.1.0
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Access to `security.*` attributes isn't free. man attr says: "Read and write access permissions to security attributes depend on the policy implemented for each security attribute by the security module. When no security module is loaded, all processes have read access to extended security attributes, and write access is limited to processes that have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability."

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to the error I was receiving, but I worked around it by letting rsync do the networking via ssh instead of going over NFS. It turns out NFS doesn't support xattrs.